# Get Network Manager name for devices from command line

Tags: network-manager

Network Manager has long names for ethernet devices in parentheses: eth0 might be shown as `Ethernet Networks (Intel Ethernet Connection I217-LM)` in the dropdown menu.

Is there a way to list these names from the command line (using nmcli?)- or even better also show the ifconfig name for them in the same output?

This is using 16.04 with nmcli 1.2.6.

Comment: You mean like `nmcli -g TYPE,NAME,DEVICE connection show --active`? `man nmcli` has lots and lots of options.

Comment: `-g` doesn't seem to be one of them, at least not on nmcli 1.2.6.

Comment: Done.  What version is your answer applicable to?  Other people with other versions may come here and find it useful.

Comment: @LucasW in nmcli 1.2.6 you should be able to replace `-g` by `-t -f` to get the same information

Comment: The TYPE prints out as 802-3-ethernet, not the long name in parentheses `(Intel Ethernet...`.  Is there another field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments above got me far enough to be able to figure out the answer:

```
$ nmcli -t -f GENERAL.PRODUCT,GENERAL.DEVICE device show
GENERAL.PRODUCT:Ethernet Connection I217-LM
GENERAL.DEVICE:eth0
```